# ASP Core Input Validation How do I require key2 when key1 is present in FromQuery or FromBody?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I have been a PHP/Laravel for most of my professional dev career, but then this year I was tasked to switch to dotnet core onwards so now I came across to a problem when I try to validate a date range input I couldn't find it somewhere in the docs but in laravel I used to do this validation

```php
$request->validate([
    'toDate'=>'required_with:fromDate'
]);
```

How can I achieve this in ASP core?

Answer (score 0):

> I try to validate a date range input I couldn't find it somewhere in the docs

You can try to create a [custom validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes) to validate `toDate` based on the value of `fromDate`, like below.

```
public class CheckEndDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string GetErrorMessage() =>
        $"ToDate must be later than FromDate.";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var note = (Note)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        var todate = ((DateTime)value);

        var fromdate = note.FromDate;

        if (todate < fromdate)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

In model class, apply that custom validation attribute to `ToDate` property

```
public class Note
{
    //other properties

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [CheckEndDate]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

Test Result

[image]